# ArrayBlockingQueue v/s BlockingBuffer.decorate(new BoundedFifoBuffer()

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

(Found this pice of code in our Production)

I read about ArrayBlockingQueue and found that it is bounded and blocked.
Now if we use - `BlockingBuffer.decorate(new BoundedFifoBuffer()` - looks like it is similar to ArrayBlockingQueue.

Please help in understanding if they are similar or different and in what scenario what to use?

Comment: `org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.BlockingBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayBlockingQueue` is a standard library, whereas `BlockingBuffer` / `BoundedFifoBuffer` is not. This would be a sufficient reason to prefer `ArrayBlockingQueue` if you don't have a particular reason.

Another strong difference is that `Buffer` is a collection but not a `Queue`, whereas `ArrayBlockingQueue` is. If your use case is a queue, then `ArrayBlockingQueue` would be preferable as there are libraries that expects a `Queue`.

Finally, `ArrayBlockingQueue` uses a bit more sophisticated concurrency control, so I wouldn't be surprised if it performs better.

Comment: Thanks! In the pasted code in Qs. Fifo has been specified(queue like behavior), so that means ArrayBlockingQueue should be preferred over BlockingBuffer / BoundedFifoBuffer. Right?

Comment: I think unless the code uses operations only available in Buffer, you should prefer ArrayBlockingQueue